# Can I write to a Windows network share from Linux (RHEL 8.2) without sudo rights?

Tags: mount, network-shares, redhat-enterprise-linux

There is a network share with an address that looks like `\\my_network_share\folder1$\folder2\folder3`. I have an application under RHEL 8.2 that needs to write files to this share.

From the [documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html-single/managing_file_systems/index#mounting-nfs-shares_managing-file-systems) I learned that you can mount the share using a command like `mount -t nfs -o options AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD:/folder1 /home/tomcat/myShare` where

- `AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD` is the IP address of the server (result of `nslookup my_network_share` under Windows) and
- `tomcat` is the user under which I am logged in RHEL.

The problem is that `mount` requires root privileges and my user does not have `sudo` rights.

Is there a way to access that share **without** being an administrator (without using `sudo`)?

Comment: I believe you can get round the root limitation by using a fuse based filesystem (see https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/fuse.html) - for example sshfs. Ive never used it, but googling I found a fuse based NFS module which might work - https://github.com/sahlberg/fuse-nfs

Comment: Actually, you may have a second issue. NFS is a Unix filesystem. You should be looking for an SMB fuse system. More googling revealed what I believe is your answer - https://askubuntu.com/questions/24348/how-do-i-mount-samba-share-as-non-root-user#24376